# In u-boot why spi flash is probed twice?

Tags: u-boot

This is a section of the log from [u-boot](https://github.com/Xilinx/u-boot-xlnx) running on Avnet Microzed board -ARM CORTEX A9:

```
[Thu Jun 26 17:40:53.656 2014]

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:53.656 2014]

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:53.656 2014] U-Boot 2013.07 (Jun 26 2014 - 17:34:41)

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:53.656 2014]

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:53.656 2014] 1 GiB

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:53.671 2014] SF: Detected S25FL129P_64K/S25FL128S_64K with page size 64 KiB, total 16 MiB

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:53.703 2014] *** Warning - bad CRC, using default environment

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:53.703 2014]

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:53.703 2014] In:    serial

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:53.703 2014] Out:   serial

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:53.703 2014] Err:   serial

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:53.703 2014] U-BOOT for ab

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:53.703 2014]

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:53.703 2014]

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:53.703 2014] SF: Detected S25FL129P_64K/S25FL128S_64K with page size 64 KiB, total 16 MiB

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:54.453 2014] SF: 5242880 bytes @ 0x520000 Read: OK

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:54.453 2014]      Description:  PetaLinux Kernel

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:54.453 2014] 0x010000f0

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:54.453 2014] 4620145 Bytes = 4.4 MiB

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:54.453 2014]      Description:  Flattened Device Tree blob

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:54.453 2014] 0x01468114

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:54.453 2014] 9766 Bytes = 9.5 KiB

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:54.453 2014]      Hash algo:    crc32

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:54.453 2014]      Hash value:   9a94aca8

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:54.453 2014]      Hash algo:    sha1

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:54.453 2014]      Hash value:
97b81e3014decb706ff19e61e1227dace97d4232

[Thu Jun 26 17:40:54.453 2014] crc32+ sha1+  Uncompressing Kernel Image ... OK

.
.
.
```

I noticed that the following lines are coming twice:

SF: Detected S25FL129P_64K/S25FL128S_64K with page size 64 KiB, total 16 MiB

This corresponds to the function [spi_flash_probe](https://github.com/Xilinx/u-boot-xlnx/blob/master/drivers/mtd/spi/sf_probe.c) from
drivers/mtd/spi/spi_flash.c

I need to know:

1- Why it is probed twice?

2- The name and location of the file from where this function is called (twice).

3- The second time it is being probed it is considerably slow, why it is so?

These are my u-boot environmental variable;

```
U-Boot-PetaLinux> printenv
autoload=no
baudrate=115200
bootdelay=4
bootenvsize=0x00020000
bootenvstart=0x00500000
bootfile=image.ub
bootsize=0x00500000
bootstart=0x00000000
clobstart=0x1000000
console=console=ttyPS0,115200
cp_dtb2ram=sf probe 0; sf read ${clobstart} ${dtbstart} ${dtbsize}
dtbboot=sf probe 0; sf read ${netstart} ${kernstart} ${kernsize}; sf read ${dtbnetstart} ${dtbstart} ${dtbsize}; bootm ${netstart} - ${dtbnetstart}
dtbnetboot=tftp ${netstart} image.ub; tftp ${dtbnetstart} system.dtb; bootm ${netstart} - ${dtbnetstart}
dtbnetstart=0x1500000
eraseconf=sf probe 0; sf erase ${confstart} ${confsize}
eraseenv=sf probe 0; sf erase ${bootenvstart} ${bootenvsize}
ethact=Gem.e000b000
ethaddr=00:0a:35:00:07:c0
fault=echo $img image size is greater than allocated place - $img is NOT UPDATED
get_dtb=run cp_dtb2ram; fdt addr ${clobstart}
hostname="Peta_MicroZed"
install_dtb=sf probe 0; sf erase ${dtbstart} ${dtbsize};sf write ${clobstart} ${dtbstart} ${filesize}
install_jffs2=sf probe 0; sf erase ${jffs2start} ${jffs2size};sf write ${clobstart} ${jffs2start} ${filesize}
install_kernel=sf probe 0; sf erase ${kernstart} ${kernsize};sf write ${fileaddr} ${kernstart} ${filesize}
install_uboot=sf probe 0; sf erase ${bootstart} ${bootsize};sf write ${clobstart} ${bootstart} ${filesize}
kernsize=0x00500000
kernstart=0x00520000
load_boot=tftp ${clobstart} BOOT.BIN
load_dtb=tftp ${clobstart} system.dtb
load_jffs2=tftp ${clobstart} rootfs.jffs2
load_kernel=tftp ${clobstart} image.ub
loadaddr=0x1000000
mtdids=nor0=0
mtdparts=mtdparts=0:5M(boot),128K(bootenv),851968(image)
nc=setenv stdout nc;setenv stdin nc;
ncip=192.168.1.11
netboot=tftp ${netstart} image.ub && bootm
netstart=0x1000000
psserial0=setenv stdout ttyPS0;setenv stdin ttyPS0
sd_update_boot=echo Updating BOOT from SD;mmcinfo && fatload mmc 0:1 ${clobstart} BOOT.BIN && run install_uboot
sd_update_kernel=echo Updating Kernel from SD;mmcinfo && fatload mmc 0:1 ${clobstart} ${bootfile}&& set fileaddr ${clobstart}&&run install_kernel
sdboot=echo boot Petalinux; mmcinfo && fatload mmc 0 ${netstart} ${bootfile}&& bootm
serial=setenv stdout serial;setenv stdin serial
serverip=192.168.1.11
sfboot=sf probe 0; sf read ${netstart} ${kernstart} ${kernsize}; bootm ${netstart}
silent=1
silent-kinux=yes
silent_linux=yes
test_crc=if imi ${clobstart}; then run test_img; else echo $img Bad CRC - $img is NOT UPDATED; fi
test_img=setenv var "if test ${filesize} -gt ${psize}; then run fault; else run ${installcmd}; fi"; run var; setenv var
update_boot=setenv img BOOT.BIN; setenv psize ${bootsize}; setenv installcmd install_uboot; run load_boot test_img; setenv img; setenv psize; setenv installcmd
update_dtb=setenv img DTB; setenv psize ${dtbsize}; setenv installcmd install_dtb; run load_dtb test_img; setenv img
update_jffs2=setenv img JFFS2; setenv psize ${jffs2size}; setenv installcmd install_jffs2; run load_jffs2 test_img; setenv img; setenv psize; setenv installcmd
update_kernel=setenv img KERNEL; setenv psize ${kernsize}; setenv installcmd "install_kernel"; run load_kernel test_crc; setenv img; setenv psize; setenv installcmd
varify=n

Environment size: 3214/131068 bytes
```

Answer (score 0):

what is the configuration file name for your board in `include/configs/` directory and where is your board specific file reside in `board/` directory? I don't have rights to comments so i have to put query as answer.
I doubt that spi flash driver initialization is done twice, once from `arch/arm/lib/board.c` and once from board specific file because of which you see SPI flash probed twice.

Answer (score 0):

The first time is probably reading the environment from SPI. That uses the setting `CONFIG_ENV_SPI_MAX_HZ`.

The second time is booting, and this is running the sfboot line in your environment.

The first command is:

```
sf probe 0
```

That uses the speed `CONFIG_SF_DEFAULT_SPEED`. Presumably this is slower.

You could update the environment command to read

```
sf probe 0 10000000
```

(10MHz) which is faster. Or you could change `CONFIG_SF_DEFAULT_SPEED`.

See `help sf` for help.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like, it's the result of resetting some important UBoot's env-var. Can you take two environment snapshots: immediately after first scan, and just before the second one?

I had the same problem with MTD rescan. The reason is **mtdids** variable, cleared in between. As for me, **ubi_part(..)** inquires the variable, and if unset, performs second MTD investigation. I suppose, you have the resembling problem.